# Device SERIAL ID in android 1.6

Tags: android

how can i get serial number in API level 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) yourActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uid = manager.getDeviceId();
```

This is working since API level 1.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to do there is several options :

- reading [Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID).  "This is a 64-bit quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots"
- using [TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29) But it's not working on all devices.

More on the subject: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html